# Please help with safety of this circuit. Safe to plug in?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, plug, outlet

I have been working on this circuit as a project for school for a few months.

Here is the schematic

[image: schematic]

It is a pulse generator that produces 100ns pulses at 220VDC. These are used to drive an ultrasonic transducer that is represented by the 50 ohm resistor between the differential probes. Cadence simulates the circuit exactly as I predict, so I am not worried about finding any surprises other than shock hazards.

Here is my circuit

[image: front]

[image: back]

[image: cable]

[image: attach]

I have a few questions that I am too paranoid to trust google with.

1. I am going to buy wood from Lowe's to make a case for this circuit. Since there is no metal chassis, do I need to solder the green earth-ground wire anywhere in my completed device? I know that it cannot be soldered to the ground of my circuit, which is the piece of copper tape on the back side. The Vpulse ground will also be separate, as it will be MCU ground. If it is necessary, I have more copper tape that I could stick somewhere within the case separate from the rest of the circuit.
2. The datasheet for my isolation transformer does not specify where the white wire 'shield' should go. Googling shield I found that it is usually connected to ground,but is not necessary. I could not get the Cadence simulation to work with the center-tapped transormer, and instead used two coupled inductors as shown in the schematic. Is leaving the shield floating okay?

Are there any other things I should be worried about before plugging it in?

Datasheet of Isolation Transformer:
https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/72306b3400a5a118df03c1c122b42c87.pdf

Comment: My immediate thought is that you don't seem to have _nearly_ enough creepage distance on that protoboard...

Comment: What part of the circuit will be user accessible? Is there a button to tell it to go? Or a switch to turn it on and off? What will you eventually connect the output to? Is the node marked as ground in your schematic connected to anything accessible?

Comment: There are two microcontrollers. An arduino is used as a GUI with an LCD. The Arduino is completely isolated from the schematic shown above, and only communicates with the Raspberry Pi through serial communication. The second MCU is the Pi. It controls when the pulse creation begins. Cadence simulations never put the voltage at the far left node of Vpulse greater than the threshhold a Pi could handle. The copper tape that acts as ground at the bottom of the PCB will only be in contact with wood.

Comment: Why is PNP reverse biased?  WHy a Pch FET ?? with source biased from 170Vac rectified and gate drive near ground with a coupling cap.  Two examples of how not to design this.!  Surprises like blown transistors from reverse Vbe bias transients are likely.

Comment: I used a P-type power mosfet because my load is the 50 ohm resistor. It's much easier to use a p-type in high side configuration. The reasoning behind the PNP is to allow the 10nF capacitor to discharge when the pulse input travels through the BJTs, which then opens the p-type mosfet for the duration of the pulse.

Comment: Yeah. But the PNP is in reverse active/saturation, which is an order of magnitude drop on hFE. I've seen designs that do this on purpose, but I see no point on doing that in here.

Comment: It seems to give me the output I need at least for the circuit overall

Comment: Maybe, but it would work better if you swapped E and C on the PNP.

Comment: I would be thinking that a fuse in the transformer primary might be a good idea! I am also suspicious about Vgs during startup, the HT rail will come up fast and you may well exceed the mosfet rating, a zenner across that 6.5k resistors seems indicated. You need some decoupling on the 12V rail, and also some on the HT rail right next to the mosfet. Bleeder resistors on the HT caps would be a good plan. Still, smoke (And the odd tickle) is how we learn and this thing has ample potential to be a learning experience...

Comment: "Cadence simulates the circuit exactly as I predict, so I am not worried about finding any surprises other than shock hazards" Oh my sweet Lord. Well, we're all young once. Go ahead. In future years you will look back on this statement and wince. To be more specific, 100 nsec pulses with ~3 A currents and 10 nsec rise times WILL give you all sorts of issues. Parasitic inductances are not your friend, and they are inevitable here. At the very least, couple your FET to your PZT with coax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected your schematic here:[image: backwards transistor]

Comment: I tested both configurations in Cadence. It seems to have no effect with regard to the 50ohm load. Why bother changing it?

Answer (score 0):

transformers like that opfen don't provide safety isolation between primary and secondary windings, (only funtional isolation) so grounding some point on the circuit on the secondary side of the transformer is a good idea.  (eg: ground the negative rail)